# Matlab - How to interdict to leave an edit text if there are errors?

Tags: matlab, callback, focus, verify

I am trying to make a GUI in wich you have to complete many edit text items, and in each edit text's callback I have to check if the value/values introduced is/are good. If a value is not correct, an Error Message will inform the user about what is wrong. Also, if the value in an edit text is not good, the user shouldn't be able to move to another edit text. I tried many solutions, but none did exactly what I want. In the next code the problem is that the user is allowed to go to another uicontrol and if i don't introduce any value, it doesn't cosider the string to be null. Please help if you can. Tnx

```
function edit_keyboard_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit_keyboard (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit_keyboard as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit_keyboard as a       double
 global matrix
 global input_method
if input_method == 1
 matrixString = get(hObject,'String');
  [lines colums] = size(matrixString);
 k=1;
if isempty(get(hObject,'String'))
   msg =  msgbox(['Complete A'],'Empty !','warn')
    return;
else
for i=1:lines

    temp = explodeString(matrixString(i,:),' ')
    cl = length(temp)
    for j=1:cl
        [num flag] = str2num(char(temp(j)));
        if flag~=1
            msg =  msgbox(['Error in line ' num2str(j) ', colum ' num2str(i) ' , input a number! '],'Not a number!','warn')
            return;
        else
            matrix(i,j) = num;
        end
    end
end
end
end
```

Comment: One way to do it: As soon as he goes somewhere, make all invalid values in the previous fields empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to interdict to go in another uicontrol if there are any errors, but the problem now is that if I don't introduce any value, it won't give an error saying that the edit text is empty. Or if I introduce a wrong value and then i go to another uicontrol, it says that i have an error and focuses on the edit text with the error, but if i don't introduce any new value, it    allows me to go to another uicontrol and it doesn't specify any errors.

Comment: If empty is not a valid value, you may want to use a different default. For example 0.

Comment: Checking if the edit text is empty works, but as I can see, it does all the checkings only if I introduce any value, including  ' ', but what i want is to do all the checkings when i leave the edit text. I can do like you said, to make the field empty, and the errors would show when i press the button continue, but I don't think this is the  most elegant way to do it..